# statsmodels.tsa.api.VAR how to plot the results

Tags: python, plot, statsmodels

I want to plot the results based on what is suggested in http://statsmodels.sourceforge.net/stable/vector_ar.html#var. However, I don't want to use pandas. The plotting doesn't work and I don't know why.

Here is my code:

```
Y = [data[0,:] , data[1,:]]
import statsmodels.tsa.api
Vmodel = statsmodels.tsa.api.VAR(zip(*Y))
results = Vmodel.fit(2)
print results.summary()
print results.plot()
results.plot_acorr()
```

results.summary() is working but plotting is not. I appreciate any help.

Comment: What's data? Can you provide a small reproducible example?

Comment: data is a multidimensional list: data[0,:] is [ 120.634   65.766 -402.844 -258.187  151.982 -370.8  ] and data[1,:] is [ 120.634   65.766 -402.844 -258.187  151.982 -370.8  ]

Comment: I think the problem is with plotting. Right?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It seems that you just not requesting that the plots are shown to you. Use can use `pylab.show()`. For example:

```
import statsmodels.tsa.api
import pylab

data = [[ 120.634, 65.766, -402.844, -258.187, 151.982, -370.8 ],
        [ 140.634, 65.766, -402.844, -358.187, 151.982, -370.8 ]] 

Y = [data[0] , data[1]]
Vmodel = statsmodels.tsa.api.VAR(zip(*Y))
results = Vmodel.fit(2)
print results.summary()
print results.plot()
results.plot_acorr()
pylab.show()
```